# Is there a way to update a JIRA issue with an already committed code revision?

Tags: jira

We're using JIRA with SVN.  We didn't have post-commit hooks working right, so some JIRA issues are missing some revisions.

Does anyone know of a way to add a revision to a JIRA issue after the fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for the code to appear under "Source" tab in JIRA is to have a link in a commit comment in version control software. And if you forgot to add it - you can [change the message](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg) manually. Although you'll have to reindex the instance for that to be applied...

Comment: marking as "the answer", since it's not answerers fault that there is no answer.